# Undefined variable:forums

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, undefined

Undefined variable gives an error What should I do?
ForumController:

```
public function index()
{
    $forums = Forum::all();
    return view('forum.index') -> withForum($forums);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('/forum','ForumController');
```

welcome.blade :

```
@foreach($forums as $forum)
 <div class="col-md-7">{{ $forum->title }}</div> 
     <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
     <span class="label label-warning">پاسخ : ۱۰</span>
     <span class="label label-primary">تشکر : ۱۰</span>
     <span class="label label-success">RaymondDragon</span>
 </div>@endforeach
```

ErrorException:

```
Undefined variable: forums (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/forums/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)
```

Comment: you are showing the wrong route and controller ... what you have here does not return a `welcome` view

Comment: Thank you so much ... I'll try and I'll announce the result.

Comment: is it possible your `forum.index` view 'includes' `welcome`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return view('forum.index') -> withForums($forums);
// or
return view('forum.index') -> with('forums', $forums);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to define the forums variable like this:

```
return view('forum.index')->with('forums', $forums);
```

Comment: I tried, but it was more the track error./opt/lampp/htdocs/forums/resources/views/welcome.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

```
return view('forum.index', ['forums' => $forums]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('forum.index', compact('forums'));
```

Is a neat way of achieving your goal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... unfortunately it did not work.Notice the above error.

Comment: Yes...As i said.

Comment: but forum.index != welcome. Those are two different blade files.

Comment: What is the file name?